# MVC question Elmah

Tags: asp.net-mvc, elmah

I am working on a MVC project where I have copied a lot of work from NerdDinner project.
In NerdDinner we are returning few views like DinnerNotFound, InvalidOwner if a dinner is not found or if a user is not an owner of the dinner. But In my project want to create an 
view (CustomException) and use it for all such reasons. So I raise exception and catch them in my basecontrller's OnException event. Then from there I want to render a Custom view after loging it to ELMAH.

But the call to render that view (RedirectToAction("CustomException",ce );)
doesnt seem working, it doenst navigate to the action CustomException.

Can someone help me what could be the reason. I have listed all the files here.
Also how should I make an entry into global.asax.cs file.
codes are given below.

Regards
Parminder

ListingExceptions.cs

namespace Listing.Exceptions
{
    public static class ListingExeceptions
    {

```
    public static CustomException GetCustomException(Exception ex)
    {
        CustomException ce = new CustomException();
        switch (ex.Message)
        {
            case ItemConstant.INVALID_OWNER:
                ce = new CustomException("Invalid Owner", "OOps you are not owner of this item");
                break;
            case ItemConstant.ITEM_NOT_FOUND:
                ce = new CustomException("Item not Found", "The Item you are looking for couldnt be found");
                break;
            default:
               ce = new CustomException("Error ", "There is an Error.");
               break;
        }

        return ce;

    }


}
```

}

BaseController.cs

namespace Listing.Controllers
{
    public partial class BaseController : Controller
    {

```
    public virtual ActionResult CustomException(CustomException ce)
    {
        return View(ce);   
    }

    protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
    {
        base.OnException(filterContext);

        CustomException ce = ListingExeceptions.GetCustomException(filterContext.Exception);
        ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(filterContext.Exception);
        filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

        RedirectToAction("CustomException",ce );
    }
}
```

}

ListingController.cs

namespace Listing.Controllers

{

public virtual ActionResult Details(long id, string title)
        {

```
        Item item = itemRepository.GetItemByID(id);

        if (item == null)

        {

            throw new Exception("ItemNotFound");

        }

        else

        {

            return View("Details", new ListingFormViewModel(item, photoRepository));

        }
    }
```

}

global.asax.cs

routes.MapRoute(
                            "Exception",                                              // Route name
                            "{controller}/{action}/{ce}",                           // URL with parameters
                            new { controller = "Base", action = "CustomException", ce = "" }                          );

Comment: Please reword your question/title so that it actually explains what you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not so sure you can redirect like that within `OnException`. Adding a `filterContext.Result =` should work:

```
protected override void OnException(ExceptionContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnException(filterContext);

    CustomException ce = ListingExeceptions.GetCustomException(filterContext.Exception);
    ErrorSignal.FromCurrentContext().Raise(filterContext.Exception);
    filterContext.ExceptionHandled = true;

    filterContext.Result = RedirectToAction("CustomException",ce );
}
```